# Cannot delete a saved image file after I am done using it

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap

I'm trying to:

1. grab an image and copy it
2. manipulate temp image (resize, draw on it, etc.)
3. save to temp folder when done manipulating
4. upload it in a web request
5. upload complete, now delete temp image

When only 1 Thread is running this works fine. When I add more than 1 thread I get this error...

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\someimage.jpg' because it is being used by another process.

Below is code I'm working with. After this code is run, I run an upload method. Once that is complete I try to delete

```
using (var img = Image.FromFile(filename))
{
    using (var newImage = ImageHandler.ScaleImage(img, 640, 960))
    {
        using (Graphics gra = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            gra.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, new Size(640, 960)));

            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat()
            {
                Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
            };

            gra.DrawString(text, new Font("Helvetica", 32), Brushes.White, new RectangleF(0, newImage.Height / 2, newImage.Width, newImage.Height), sf);
            temp_filename = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/temp/" + GenerateDateTimeNowStamp() + ".jpg";
            newImage.Save(temp_filename);
        }
    }
}


//run upload method ...


//delete temp file
if(System.IO.File.Exists(temp_filename))
    System.IO.File.Delete(temp_filename);
```

Comment: What is `GenerateDateTimeNowStamp()` and how granular are the results it returns? Also, why not [`GetTempFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` to create my temp file names and then they wont clash...

```
var tempFolder = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory , "temp");   
temp_filename = Path.Combine(tempFolder, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

or

```
temp_filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
```

oh yes I prefer to use path.Combine

Comment: If you still want to use time, I would use another function, maybe DateTime.Now.

Comment: You could still get a clash if the two threads call the DateTime.Now at the same time, OK it's getting smaller, but it still possible....

Answer (score 1):

> When only 1 Thread is running this works fine. When I add more than 1
>   thread I get this error...

Problem is with `GenerateDateTimeNowStamp` method. Even when `n` number of threads call `GenerateDateTimeNowStamp` it is going to return **same value at particular time**, multiple threads end up using the same file, that's why you can't delete it while another thread may be using it(half the way in save).

As suggested by @Damien_The_Unbeliever in comment, I recommend using `Path.GetTempFileName()`

Comment: The thing is that i see all the files in the temp folder being saved correctly.

Comment: how do you claim that they are unique? post `GenerateDateTimeNowStamp` method implementation